# Button is clickable but doesn't proceed to the next page- Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am facing a problem while clicking on a button. I have multiple scenarios and in each scenario i should click on this button, when i click on this button should take me to another page. This button randomly failed when i run the test several time. e.g : I run the unit test all the scenarios work but one of them failed i repeat the test all the scenarios succeed but i have a new failed scenario

This error because the button didn't redirect to the next page

```
Message: Test method BnI.UITests.Register.CancelOfficialInfoTest threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: (.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Name:'])[1]/following::input[1]
```

The method i use to click on the button

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(),'Proceed')]"))).Click();
```

HTML :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 no-padding-sides">
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4 no-padding-sides bottom-actions">
   <button class="btn custom-btn custom-blue" type="submit">
   Proceed
   </button>
   <button type="button" class="btn custom-btn custom-grey" (click)="cancelRegistration()"> Cancel </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Selector in your code doesn't match the one from Exception log. Also using `WebDriverWait` should lead to `TimeoutException`, but not to `NoSuchElementException`. Update your question appropriately

Comment: the error is because the button didn't redirect to the next page.

Comment: So button was found and clicked, but it made no effect, right? Try `Submit()` instead of `Click()`

Comment: yes what you said is correct.. i tried submit same result

Comment: Do you need to perform any other actions before submitting? Like filling some input fields, etc... If so, are you sure that those actions performed correctly?

Comment: yes i need to fill some field and yes everything is fine. Man the same test failed if i run it again will work fine !!

Comment: Did you try to wait until each input fields' `@value` returns required text? e.g. if you send `"username"` into input field, try to wait until `GetAttribute("value")` of this input field returns `"username"`... It would also be helpful if you share the URL if it's not a private page

Comment: server is local so i can't share the url :(.. can you proceed your answer please

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to do the same in C#... In Python I would do something like `user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="username"]'); user.send_keys("Username"); WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver: user.get_attribute('value') == "Username")`...